# Can't switch TripleDES to CFB or OFB mode

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, 3des, tripledes

I'm encrypting some data using `TripleDES` and three different modes (`CBC`, `CFB` and `OFB`) like this:

```
using (TripleDES alg = TripleDES.Create())
{
    var param = GetParams();
    alg.KeySize = param.keySize;
    alg.BlockSize = param.blockSize;
    alg.Key = param.sessionKey;
    alg.IV = param.IV;
    alg.Mode = param.mode;

    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = alg.CreateEncryptor(alg.Key, alg.IV))
```

The last line throws an exception (`Specified cipher mode is not valid for this algorithm.`) whenever I use `CFB` or `OFB` as the mode.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Topaco `GetParams()` is my function for getting these values. What do you mean by  .NET variant?

Comment: @Topaco In the NuGet manager I have .NET Core downloaded

Comment: From the bottom of that page about support for CFB / OFB in .NET core: "Added support for CFB to **AES** (#15771) #38211". Uh, yeah.

Comment: Note that the Bouncy Castle cryptography library for .NET should contain all these modes, but beware that it will use software to encrypt, no hardware acceleration or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically because it is not supported by .Net Core.
See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/38211

Except if you are working on a legacy code, you should use AES instead of 3DES.